# Factory function unable to return the local iterator to for loop in lua?

Tags: for-loop, lua, iterator, local, lua-5.3

Why can't the factory function `fromto` return the local function `iter` as an iterator to the for loop?

```
function fromto(from,to)
    return iter,to,from-1
end

local function iter(to,from)--parameter:invariant state, control variable
    from = from + 1
    if from <= to then
        return from
    else
        return nil
    end
end

for i in fromto(1,10) do
    print(i)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @YuHao says, your scheme can work. There are a few ways you could rearrange your code. Here's one:

```
local function fromto(from,to)
    --parameter:invariant state, control variable
    local function iter(to,from)
        from = from + 1
        if from <= to then
            return from
        else
            return nil
        end
    end

    return iter,to,from-1
end


for i in fromto(1,10) do
    print(i)
end
```

Two things to understand: variable scope and functions are values.

1. Variables are either global or local. Local variables are lexically scoped. They are in scope from the statement following their declaration up to the end of the block. If a name is not the name of a local variable it becomes a global variable reference. On your line 2, `iter` is a global variable.
2. Functions are not declared, they are values created when a function definition expression is executed. (A function defintion statement is simply an alternate syntax for a function definition expression and assignment to a variable.) Also, functions don't have names. They are simply referenced by one or more variables. So, your function value does exist and get referenced by the `iter` variable until execution control passes through the lines that contain the function definition. In your code, that's the end of line 11.

Comment: so I just need to declare the function `iter` before `fromto` returns it. also a function can use a local variable that is declare outside of its scope and below its scope,right??

Comment: No functions are not "declared." The issue is with variables and scope. A global variable is always in scope, though it might be hidden by other variables with the same name. A local variable's scope is from after the point it is declared up to the end of the block it is declared in. So, your `iter` is a local variable that is in scope from your line 11 to 15. See [Visibility Rules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.5).

Comment: Note: the `iter` variable does not need to be in scope where you use the function value. You're returning the function value from your factory function so the value lives on to be called repeated by the for statement.

Answer (score 2):

The factory / iterator function is implemented correctly. The problem is, by using

```
local function iter(to,from)
  --...
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
local iter = function(to,from)
  --...
end
```

`iter` is a local variable that `fromto` has no access to. Remove `local` and it will run.

Comment: could also put `iter`  before `fromto` in the file

Comment: but I thought if the local variable is declare in the same chunck as the other function, the other function will have acess to it??